# Build proguard from it's source code

Tags: java, build, proguard

While using proguard from inside Eclipse on my Unity3d application, I get an error that is caused by corrupt StackMapTable attributes.  I found that this is a known issue, whose workaround is to tell proguard to ignore the StackMapTable attributes by modifying a definition in its ClassConstants.java, and then rebuild proguard and replace the proguard.jar in the Android SDK:

http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/420/

I downloaded the latest proguard source code (v.5.1), and modified ClassConstants.java as necessary.  However, no matter how much I try, I just cannot build proguard successfully, which is the second step in the process.

I tried for hours, but it seems that I'm missing something that it's obvious for seasoned Java programmers. I tried creating a new Java Project in Eclipse and copying all the proguard src folder in the src folder in Eclipse, and the exporting to jar. With this, I get many compile warnings and errors. I think this is because the proguard.ant package uses many imports, such as import org.apache.tools.ant.*; And also package proguard.wtk imports com.sun.kvem.environment.Obfuscator; I've searched all over the net for these libraries, but can't find them to add them to the project.

Also, I tried from a command prompt: javac ProGuard.java from inside the src/proguard/ folder, and the process finishes with 61 errors.

Any search that I've made on how to build proguard from its source code, returns results that are relevant to the use and configuration of proguard.

Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build proguard from its source code using ant:

1. Install ant if not already installed.
2. Create a build.xml file, or use the build.xml file provided by proguard
3. Open a command prompt in the same folder as the build.xml file, and run "ant"

That's it.  Ant will build proguard, and describe it progress in the command prompt window.

To download and install ant:

http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi

http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Comment: This information seems outdated, because the latest ProGuard also requires Gradle and some `wtk.home`.